# Volume generation by rotation of $y=x^2-1$ and $y=3-x^2$

Tags: calculus, volume

Find the volume generated by the rotation about the $Y-axis$ of the area between the curves in the first and fourth quadrant $y=x^2-1$ and $y=3-x^2$ using method of cylindrical shells.

Now height of shell is $(x^2-1)-(3-x^2)$ but what will be the radius? Will it be $x$? What should be kept in mind in such questions to obtain radius.

[image]

Comment: Assuming you're integrating with respect to x, I believe the radius will be x.

Comment: The height is $(3-x^2)-(x^2-1)$ (no big problem if you keep your version, but yours will give a negative integral). The radius is $x$.