# Volume of rotation of $y=x^2-1$ and $y=3-x^2$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Find the volume generated by the rotation about the $Y$ axis of the area between the curves in the first and fourth quadrant $y=x^2-1$ and $y=3-x^2$ (using  cylindrical shells).

The problem with this question is that height of shell changes after $x=1$. Do we split our integral in two parts? Will radius be same for both integrals?

Comment: @AndréNicolas But both graphs are above $x$ axis after $x=1$. I was solving taking height as $(3-x^2)-(x^2-1)$ but it seems wrong.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653730/volume-generation-by-rotation-of-y-x2-1-and-y-3-x2

Comment: @AndréNicolas But what about the region that exists from $0$ to $1$?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Wouldn't the integral for volume $\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}} x(4-2x^2) dx$ become 0?

Comment: We integrate from $0$ to $\sqrt{2}$.  (You forgot the $2\pi$.)

Comment: @AndréNicolas But why so? If we draw sketch, area is enclosed from $-\sqrt{2}$ to $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: You are rotating the first and fourth quadrant part of the region between the curves., that is, the region to the right of the $y$-axis.